# IIS7 URL Rewrite multiple domains to a single domain including google analytics referral code

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config, google-analytics

I am trying to elegantly capture a large number of domains that need to redirect to a single domain for example:

> mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com, mydomain-eu.com, mydomain.eu
>
> all to the main domain:
>
> www.mydomain.co.uk

This I can do fairly easily in IIS by creating a site - binding all the domains and doing a redirect.

However there is a catch. The client wants to track where those redirects came from in google analytics.

So they need some parameters passing in the redirect URL, example (using a domain from above):

> mydomain.eu 
>   redirects to:
>   www.mydomain.co.uk?utm_campaign=mydomain.eu&utm_source=mydomain.eu&utm_medium=referral

So - this is a good case to use a URL rewrite. This is what I have in the web.config:

```
   <rule name="Redirect" enabled="false" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.mydomain.co.uk$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/?utm_campaign={R:0}&amp;utm_source={R:0}&amp;utm_medium=referral" />
        </rule>
```

If the input does not match the domain I want to be I am redirecting it.

It works perfectly apart from one thing. I just cant get the parameter of the original domain. The {R:0} returns blank. I have tried {C:0} also. I have tested the patterns in the GUI and they tell me I should be getting the requested domain.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess but what about:

```
<rule name="Redirect" enabled="false" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.mydomain.co.uk$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/?utm_campaign={HTTP_HOST}&amp;utm_source={HTTP_HOST}&amp;utm_medium=referral" />
</rule>
```

Looked this up and it says you can use it this way in this documentation:

- http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#UsingServerVars

Comment: Bang on the money! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @rtpHarry for the guidance. Although the above rule didn't work for me, I managed to tweak it for my IIS7 server.

```
<rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.tsogosundigishare.com$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.tsogosundigishare.com/" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

By removing the `enabled="false"` and `patternSyntax` from the rule, it converted the rule from being "`Wildcard`" to "`Regular Expression`" and adding `redirectType="SeeOther"` redirected properly.