# iis7 redirect from url without query strings to url with query strings

Tags: url-rewriting, asp-classic, google-analytics, iis-7.5, query-string

My web programmer is having a hard time accomplishing a request.  My guess is I'm not framing the question correctly since I'm not a programmer.
What I know about our website configuration:
The site is running on windows server 2008  IIS 7.5 using ASP.
what I don't know:  I don't know if URL rewrite extension is installed.

What I'm trying to do:
vanitysub.domain.com will point to actualsub.domain.com with query string variables for Google Analytics campaign tagging appended to actualsub.domain.com

The programmer was not able to do this.  I received an email with the following.  "I think it has to do with the aliases I’m trying to redirect.  They are both bound to the same site."

Potentially useful information:
Currently if you type in the vanitysub.domain.com it renders the correct site but the URL stays vanitysub.domain.com.

Side note: This is a Google analytics issue as well because our site has over 15 different subdomains so I have configured GA to prepend the sub.domain.com to the URI.  With the current scenario this generates two separate lines in my pageview report.  One for vanitysub and one for actual sub.

Can someone help me provide instruction for how to achieve "what I'm trying to do" both without the rewrite extension and with it?  The programmer does not have time to research it.  I'm not a programmer but know enough to know I can be dangerous(i.e. it can be done) so I need your help.

Thank you!

Comment: IMHO, you need to give him (the programmer) the needed research time, because he is the person that will implement your idea. Giving you the general idea of "what to do" and later you giving the idea to the programmer, a lot of details will be lost. resulting in a loss of time, because the programmer will need to research them.

Comment: Thank you Rafael.  The issue is that I work for a public university and she simply doesn't have enough time in the day to research all that she would like and there are bigger fish to fry then my vanity url redirect with tagging.  So I can save her a lot of time by finding relevant documentation or examples from people who have dealt with this before.  If I can remove a few steps for her than I can increase the likelihood of her finding time to accomplish this task.

Comment: Do you have Remote Desktop access to your server.  If you do then you can open IIS manager.  If the URL rewrite module is installed then there'll be an icon for it.  If it isn't installed then it's easy enough to install it. (If you don't have RDP access then ask your hosting tech support if URL rewriting is available)

Comment: Thank you for the answers.  Based on some previous quests and a better explanation of my need, we were able to get this figured out!

Answer (score 0):

We were able to follow the steps outlined in a similar post with some modifications since this was only one domain and the tagging was fixed.  [IIS7 URL Rewrite multiple domains to a single domain including google analytics referral code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787007/iis7-url-rewrite-multiple-domains-to-a-single-domain-including-google-analytics)